# Why aren't BeforeTransaction and AfterTransaction methods firing?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-jdbc

I have some unit tests that use JUnit and Spring to test a simple DAO.

My understanding is that when I mark a class as @Transactional, the @BeforeTransaction and @AfterTransaction methods should run before and after my @Test methods. However, these methods are not being fired at all. I don't see any output from the before & after methods, and if I add breakpoints they don't get hit.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("/app.properties")
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestDataSourceConfiguration.class, GeneralConfiguration.class}, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TestBreadDAO {

    @Autowired
    private BreadDAO breadDAO;

    @BeforeTransaction
    public void beforeTransaction() {
        System.out.println("Hello from beforeTransaction!");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRetrieve() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Hello from testRetrieve!");
        Bread bread = breadDAO.retrieveBreadById("1");
        Assert.assertTrue(bread != null);
        Assert.assertTrue(bread.getBreadId().equals("1"));
        Assert.assertTrue(bread.getSesameSeeds() == 41000);
        Assert.assertTrue(bread.getOats() == 100000);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Hello from testInsert!");
        Bread bread = new Bread();
        bread.setBreadId("20");
        bread.setSesameSeeds(15000);
        bread.setOats(30000);
        breadDAO.insertBread(Bread);
        Bread bread2 = breadDAO.retrieveBreadById("20");
        Assert.assertTrue(bread.getBreadId().equals(bread2.getBreadId()));
        Assert.assertTrue(bread.getSesameSeeds() == bread2.getSesameSeeds());
        Assert.assertTrue(bread.getOats() == bread2.getOats());
    }

    @AfterTransaction
    public void afterTransaction() {
        System.out.println("Hello from afterTransaction!");
        Bread bread = breadDAO.retrieveBreadById("20");
        Assert.assertTrue(bread == null);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from testInsert! 
Hello from testRetrieve!
```

**EDIT**: Fixed this by adding this bean to my configuration.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager txMgr = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    txMgr.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return txMgr;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, I would extract all your `assert` statements into a separate method and call it something meaningful, for instance `assertThatItRetrievesTheRightBread(Bread bread)`. Every `JUnit` test must have one *logical* assert and this way, it's less equivocal.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea. I should brush up on best practices with respect to that; if you have a link I'll check it out.

Comment: You can check out the [Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clean-code-discussion/4yv2w5I36nU) on best practices for unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To enable support for transactions, however, you must configure a PlatformTransactionManager bean in the ApplicationContext

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html